# Why is the copy constructor of the string used?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
class TestClass
{
public:
  TestClass(){};

  std::string GetTestString()
  {
    return (mTestString);
  }
  void SetTestString(const std::string& rTestString)
  {
    mTestString = rTestString;
  }

private:
  std::string mTestString;
};

TestClass* pGlobalVar;

void SomeFunction(TestClass MyClass)
{
  pGlobalVar->SetTestString("cba");
  std::cout << "Changed string:  " << pGlobalVar->GetTestString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Copied string:   " << MyClass.GetTestString() << std::endl;

}

int main()
{
  pGlobalVar = new TestClass();
  pGlobalVar->SetTestString("abc");
  std::cout << "Original string: " << pGlobalVar->GetTestString() << std::endl;
  SomeFunction(*pGlobalVar);
  delete (pGlobalVar);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Original string: abc
Changed string:  cba
Copied string:   abc
```

As I did not define a copy constructor for my class, I would expect that a flat copy would be made, including the pointer in the `std::string`. Apparently though the `std::string` copy constructor is used, since a change to the original string did not change the copy.

Can anyone explain to me why it did not make flat copy?

I'm using Linux with GCC 4.4.6.

Comment: `std::string` was designed such that (at least with respect to copying) it behaves like `int`. If the member `mTestString` were of type `int`, then `pGlobalVar->mTestString` would not be modified from the call to `SomeFunction`. The same happens with `std::string`, by design. This is a highly desirable feature of C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> As I did not define a copy constructor for my class, I would expect that a flat copy would be made

Since you didn’t define a copy constructor, C++ did for you.

The auto-generated copy constructor calls the constructor for all its member variables (if they have one).

Analogously, auto-generated constructors call all their members’ constructors, and destructors call all their members’ destructors.

Comment: Strictly speaking all classes declare a copy constructor. The type having a non-POD member is not a prerequisite to declaring or defining that constructor. (You make it look like it is, but perhaps that is not your intent.)

Comment: @Luc I wasn’t aware of that. Can you cite the relevant paragraph from the standard? After all, POD classes don’t have regular constructors, only initialisers.

Comment: 12.8 Copying and moving class objects [class.copy] paragraph 7: "If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy constructor, one is declared implicitly. [...]" What you're likely thinking of is that a special member may be trivial, e.g. in `struct foo { int i; }`. It's still allowed to write `static_cast<foo& (foo::*)(foo const&)>(&foo::operator=)` however (paragraph 2 of clause 12) -- it's hard to argue that there is no copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 5):

> As I did not define a copy constructor for my class, I would expect that a flat copy would be made, including the pointer in the std::string.

No, the implicitly generated copy-constructor will copy each data member (and base subobject) using its copy constructor if it has one.

> Can anyone explain to me why it did not make flat copy?

Because that would be horribly broken. A class defines a copy constructor because it has to be copied in a certain way; in the case of `std::string`, it has to create a new buffer. If the new string simply held a copy of the other's pointer, then both would think they owned the same buffer, and both would try to deallocate it when they were destroyed.